# Regex difference incase on URL matching

Tags: regex

My Aim is should match URL with regex.

```
Regex_1: ^/jquery/[a-zA-Z0-9-./]{0,32}$

Regex_2: ^/jquery/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/]{0,32}$
```

URL should be match:

```
URL: /jquery/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
URL: /jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
```

My Confusion is what is difference in Regex 1 and Regex 2.

\ (backslash) in regex 2 what will be effect.

already Test this regex in Regexpal.com but not able to find Difference in Regex 1 & 2.

Please Help me.

Comment: the first will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Regex_1` and `Regex_2` has no difference.

You don't need to escape `.`, `/` inside `[..]`, because they lose their special meaning inside `[...]`.

But `-` is need to be escaped if you mean literal `-`, but in the regular expression given `-` is not inbetween two characters, so it match literal `-`.

Comment: Means when use ^/jquery/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/]{0,32}$

1. it will escape . - and /.

2. but my aim is to match not Escape so For that may I have to go with Regex 1 options ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: @ManthanPatel, `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/]` matches any alphabet (lower, upper case), digit, `-`, `.`, `/` (1); so the regular expression match the url that starts with `/jquery/` and followed by 0 ~ 32 characters (1)

Comment: @ManthanPatel, So the regular expression does not match the second url because the second url contains 44 trailing characters.

Comment: @ManthanPatel, As I said in the answer, both have same meaning.